# Bluetooth not working Lenovo G580 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, usb, bluetooth

I have problem with Bluetooth. I can't turn it on.

```
3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet [1969:1090] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3979]
Kernel driver in use: alx

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3218]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 5986:0295 Acer, Inc
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1d57:001d Xenta
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[   20.032488] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[   20.032507] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   20.032512] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   20.032514] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   20.032520] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   20.162104] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   20.162108] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   20.162112] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   20.174904] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   20.174911] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   20.174918] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[0.141199] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[15.151260] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
bluetooth             491520  10 bnep,rfcomm
```

```
$ rfkill list all

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Any solution?

Comment: This is not a bluetooth. You can remove this output. It is something wrong with the bios, the bluetooth module is not shown at all.

Comment: That happened when i upgrade windows 7 to 10 and installed clean windows 10 with ubuntu 14.04 :/

Comment: There might be a sticker on the bottom of the laptop with the wifi cards model number, can you find it?  It will be something like AR5B???

Comment: There is only shortcut Fn + F5 On-Off wireless connection: Qualcomm Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0 Port_#0003.Hub_#0004 on windows 10 power connection = off and i cant turn on but drivers are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. Problem was in BIOS [Boot] section. I changed **UEFI Boot - Disabled** and bluetooth works perfectly now.

Comment: Strange as my bluetooth is detected on my Lenovo G710 with the same wifi whether UEFI is enabled or not

Comment: Yes it is, i think it's BIOS problem now Bluetooth work perfect on Win7 Win10 Ubunu and Android_x86_5.1

Answer (score 1):

If wifi or Bluetooth are disabled from Windows Lenovo Power Management(LPM) on Lenovo G850, they don't work in Linux as well. Since, for whatever reason (bug in Windows 10, bug in LPM for Win10, using incompatible(ie. made for Win7) LPM on Win10, you're unable to switch it on in Windows, you're being unable to use it in GNU/Linux as well.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2239746&page=2

This wiered behaviour is not limited to Lenovo, here's what I found about a certain Dell laptop:

"For Dell laptops install the latest drivers from Dell's website in Windows in order for the bluetooth module to work in Linux. (Required for D430 with Gutsy / Hardy and D830 and D630)
...Go to a utility in Windows to turn it on before you can reinstall the driver. If you turn the card off in Windows reenable the card so Ubuntu can recognize it."

Source:https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup

So, the possible solution is to try to get the BT switched on from LPM in Windows. Maybe you should try LPM for win7 on Win 10 if you're using LPM for win10 on Win 10 or vice versa. If that doesn't work, you may need to install (preferably triple boot) win7 and enable the BT from LPM for win7 on Win 7.

(I don't think this qualifies as an answer, but I don't have enough reps to put this in comments)

Comment: I installed LPM from win7 on 10 in compatibile mode and dosen't work at all. I think i have to install win7. i will try it tomorrow. Thanks!