# Bluetooth disabled in Lenovo G580 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, lenovo

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and now I can't turn on Bluetooth. I also installed Blueman, but it still doesn't work. I found this other forum entry ([Bluetooth not working Lenovo G580 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695985/bluetooth-not-working-lenovo-g580-ubuntu-14-04-lts)) and it solved it by turning on the Bluetooth in BIOS, but now I can't get into the BIOS.

Results of `lshw`:

```
description: Notebook
product: 20157 (System SKUNumber)
vendor: LENOVO
version: Lenovo G580
serial: WB12382839WB0308190L
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
configuration: administrator_password=unknown boot=normal chassis=notebook family=ChiefRiver System frontpanel_password=unknown keyboard_password=unknown power-on_password=unknown sku=System SKUNumber uuid=352051C0-09DC-11E3-832D-A79E27E8AC90
      *-core
           description: Motherboard
           product: Emerald Lake 2
           vendor: LENOVO
           physical id: 0
           version: FAB1
           serial: WB12382839
           slot: Part Component
 *-firmware
      description: BIOS
      vendor: LENOVO
      physical id: 0
      version: 62CN42WW
      date: 10/23/2012
      size: 128KiB
      capacity: 4032KiB
      capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video pc98 acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot uefi
 *-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 4
      bus info: cpu@0
      version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz
      serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
      slot: CPU Socket - U3E1
      size: 1204MHz
      capacity: 1204MHz
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 100MHz
      capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms cpufreq
      configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
 *-cache:0
      description: L1 cache
      physical id: 5
      slot: L1-Cache
      size: 32KiB
      capacity: 32KiB
      capabilities: internal write-through data
 *-cache:1
      description: L1 cache
      physical id: 6
      slot: L1-Cache
      size: 32KiB
      capacity: 32KiB
      capabilities: internal write-through instruction
 *-cache:2
      description: L2 cache
      physical id: 7
      slot: L2-Cache
      size: 256KiB
      capacity: 256KiB
      capabilities: internal write-through unified
 *-cache:3
      description: L3 cache
      physical id: 8
      slot: L3-Cache
      size: 3MiB
      capacity: 3MiB
      capabilities: internal write-back unified
 *-memory
      description: System memory
      physical id: 34
      slot: System board or Motherboard
      size: 4GiB
    *-bank:0
         description: DIMMProject-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>POT-Creation-Date: 2009-10-08 14:02+0200PO-Revision-Date: 2012-03-14 06:38+0000Last-Translator: Paco Molinero <paco@byasl.com>Language-Team: Spanish <es@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2014-11-10 11:11+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 17241) [vacío]
         physical id: 0
         slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
    *-bank:1
         description: DIMMProject-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>POT-Creation-Date: 2009-10-08 14:02+0200PO-Revision-Date: 2012-03-14 06:38+0000Last-Translator: Paco Molinero <paco@byasl.com>Language-Team: Spanish <es@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2014-11-10 11:11+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 17241) [vacío]
         physical id: 1
         slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
    *-bank:2
         description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
         product: SHARETRONIC
         vendor: 0000
         physical id: 2
         serial: 8C651505
         slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
         size: 4GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
    *-bank:3
         description: DIMMProject-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>POT-Creation-Date: 2009-10-08 14:02+0200PO-Revision-Date: 2012-03-14 06:38+0000Last-Translator: Paco Molinero <paco@byasl.com>Language-Team: Spanish <es@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2014-11-10 11:11+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 17241) [vacío]
         physical id: 3
         slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
 *-pci
      description: Host bridge
      product: 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 09
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      configuration: driver=ivb_uncore
      resources: irq:0
    *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 09
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
         resources: irq:43 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
    *-usb:0
         description: USB controller
         product: 7 series/C210 series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 14
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
         version: 04
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:40 memory:f0600000-f060ffff
    *-communication
         description: Communication controller
         product: 7 series/C210 series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 16
         bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
         version: 04
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
         resources: irq:42 memory:f0615000-f061500f
    *-usb:1
         description: USB controller
         product: 7 series/C210 series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1a
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
         version: 04
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
         resources: irq:16 memory:f0619000-f06193ff
    *-multimedia
         description: Audio device
         product: 7 series/C210 series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1b
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
         version: 04
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
         resources: irq:44 memory:f0610000-f0613fff
    *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 7 series/C210 series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
         version: c4
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:16
    *-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 7 series/C210 series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
         version: c4
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:17 memory:f0500000-f05fffff
       *-network
            description: Network controller
            product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
            vendor: Broadcom Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            version: 01
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
            configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
            resources: irq:17 memory:f0500000-f0503fff
    *-pci:2
         description: PCI bridge
         product: 7 series/C210 series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
         version: c4
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:19 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:f0400000-f04fffff
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
            vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
            logical name: eth0
            version: 10
            serial: 3c:97:0e:a5:6e:5d
            capacity: 100Mbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
            resources: irq:45 memory:f0400000-f043ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
    *-usb:2
         description: USB controller
         product: 7 series/C210 series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
         version: 04
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
         resources: irq:23 memory:f0618000-f06183ff
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
         version: 04
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
         resources: irq:0
    *-storage
         description: SATA controller
         product: 7 series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
         version: 04
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
         resources: irq:41 ioport:3088(size=8) ioport:3094(size=4) ioport:3080(size=8) ioport:3090(size=4) ioport:3060(size=32) memory:f0617000-f06177ff
    *-serial unclaimed
         description: SMBus
         product: 7 series/C210 series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 04
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:f0614000-f06140ff ioport:efa0(size=32)
 *-scsi:0
      physical id: 1
      logical name: scsi0
      capabilities: emulated
    *-disk
         description: ATA Disk
         product: WDC WD5000LPVT-2
         vendor: Western Digital
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sda
         version: 1A02
         serial: WD-WXH1E43KWYV5
         size: 465GiB (500GB)
         capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
         configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=b0ab7bcf-3834-4e0e-8702-0418d54a5c0d sectorsize=4096dad
       *-volume:0 unclaimed
            description: Windows FAT volumen
            vendor: mkfs.fat
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
            version: FAT16
            serial: fc7d-d3e0
            size: 154MiB
            capacity: 155MiB
            capabilities: boot fat initialized
            configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat name=primary
       *-volume:1
            description: Linux swap volumen
            vendor: Windows
            physical id: 2
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
            logical name: /dev/sda2
            version: 1
            serial: 7592e1f9-b3e9-42e1-8bc0-f11a368b0f54
            size: 2054MiB
            capacity: 2054MiB
            capabilities: swap initialized
            configuration: filesystem=swap name=primary pagesize=4095
       *-volume:2
            description: partition EXT4
            vendor: Linux
            physical id: 3
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
            logical name: /dev/sda3
            logical name: /
            version: 1.0
            serial: e782a5be-8342-4950-bbf8-e4adc940ed1c
            size: 463GiB
            capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
            configuration: created=2015-07-17 14:49:29 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2015-12-29 23:41:40 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2015-12-29 23:41:40 state=mounted
       *-volume:3
            description: BIOS Boot partition
            vendor: EFI
            physical id: 4
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
            logical name: /dev/sda4
            serial: 0928bfac-2d48-494e-b82d-2e475b0a3dc4
            capacity: 1006KiB
            capabilities: nofs
            configuration: name=BIOS-GRUB
 *-scsi:1
      physical id: 2
      logical name: scsi4
      capabilities: emulated
    *-cdrom
         description: DVD-RAM writer
         product: DVDRAM GT80N
         vendor: HL-DT-ST
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/cdrom
         logical name: /dev/sr0
         version: LN80
         capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
         configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
 *-scsi:2
      physical id: 3
      bus info: usb@1:1.3
      logical name: scsi6
      capabilities: emulated scsi-host
      configuration: driver=usb-storage
    *-disk
         description: SCSI Disk
         product: Card  Reader
         vendor: Multiple
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sdb
         version: 1.00
         capabilities: removable
         configuration: sectorsize=512
       *-medium
            physical id: 0
            logical name: /dev/sdb
      *-battery
           product: Smart Battery
           vendor: Intel Corp.
           physical id: 1
           version: 2008
           serial: 1.0
           slot: Rear
      *-power unclaimed
           description: TBD by ODM
           product: TBD by ODM
           vendor: TBD by ODM
           physical id: 2
           version: 1.0
           serial: TBD by ODM
           capacity: 32768mWh
      *-network
           description: Wireless Interface
           physical id: 3
           logical name: wlan0
           serial: 0c:84:dc:1e:74:b6
           capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.16.0-57-generic firmware=610.812 ip=192.168.1.71 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Comment: Edit your question to include results from `lsusb; dmesg | egrep 'blue|firm'` Thanks as the post you linked to had different wifi/bluetooth chipsets

Comment: did you tried rfkill list?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of you not being able to access the BIOS, you should use the following steps:

1. When the computer is booting up, repeatedly press  <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd>. (try one at a time)
2. Or just check the computer's manual for the correct key! **;-)**